# Four-phase power from one-phase?

Tags: ac, phase

I have four AC electromagnets that I want to drive 90 degrees out of phase with each other. I want this device to work on regular wall-socket power. I could drive two electromagnets 180 degrees out of phase by swapping the leads on one of them - but how can I get the other two to be 90 degrees out of phase from them? I have thought about using a capacitor to tune them, but I am not sure if that is practical.

Comment: Please add information about voltage and current required for the electromagnets. Do you need variable frequency?

Comment: Hook AC to single phase motor. Tie motor axle to two AC generator axles set in-line. Now rotate one of the AC generators 90 degrees with respect to the other AC generator. Measure and continue to adjust the rotated position of one of the AC generators until the exact phase angle desired is reached. Done.

Comment: Sine waves? Square wave OK? ...

Comment: In addition to the requests for additional information to be edited into your question, (1) what is the inductance of the solenoids? What is the "regular wall socket power" voltage and frequency? (You are on an international site.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "regular wall-socket power." That is typically 120 V, 60 Hz or 240 V, 50 Hz or something close to that depending on where you live. Capacitors might be ok, but any change in the magnetic circuit will have an effect. Another option is change the AC to DC then use complex switching circuits to simulate multi-phase AC. Most such requirements are too complex to recommend an approach with a simple answer.